# How to enable Wallpaper Change Transition in Windows 10 using UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I can successfully use this [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings) to apply an Image as a wallpaper to Desktop and Lockscreen.

How do I enable Wallpaper change transition (Fade-In and Fade-Out)?

```
async Task<bool> SetWallpaperAsync(string localAppDataFileName) 
{ 
    bool success = false;
    if (UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported())
    {
        var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Local/" + localAppDataFileName);
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
        var profileSettings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;
        success = await profileSettings.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(file);
    }
    return success;
}
```

I need something that works for UWP Applications.

Comment: Hi, UWP currently does not provide related APIs to set the switching effect of the wallpaper. When you use the above code for wallpaper replacement, the wallpaper will take effect immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in UWP and I don't think the system has this currently itself. When you go into Settings - Personalization and change the wallpaper, you can see the wallpaper also changes immediately. Same things goes for when you have a slideshow set up. On the other hand, if such a smooth transition gets implemented on the OS level, then I am sure the effect will be the same across the board, even when wallpaper is changed from UWP. So it is definitely something worth suggesting in the Windows Feedback Hub.

There are some desktop customization programs that use hacky solutions to display animations or even videos on the desktop, but those are low level and performance-expensive.